# A very noob question about installing Lazy Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm interested in [this plugin](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/) but honestly I don't know how to install LazyLoad without adding data-src or putting width/height value into a very basic img bbcode?

Seems easily if it's a HTML

```
<img src="image-link" data-src="image-link" width="x" height="y" />
```

But, how about an IMG bbcode?

```
[img]image-link[/img]
[img(100px,100px)]image-link[/img]
```

Or, in another case using existed img class

```
<a href="" class="abc"><img src="image-link" /></a>
```

Comment: `how about an IMG bbcode` - easy, rewrite the server code that "translates" IMG bbcode `<img>` to add the required attribute/class ... the BBCODE could be simple, depends on the "BB"

Comment: You could take a look at implementing and configuring Google Pagespeed module with Nginx or Apache. It would allow your server to "automatically/on-the-fly" apply various optimization to your images. It also has [lazyload](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-lazyload-images) options, auto src-set for responsive, spriting, compressing, converting to webp... It's not on the code level, but on your webserver one (it need no file or code edit, but tests and config optimizations).

Answer (score -1):

BBCodes are intentionally invented to express a strict state of tags as less complex (non-HTML) representations. Lazy Loading of images should be done by media queries (for backgrounds) or media query bound javascript sources and injecting them to the DOM (this point of view is based on the fact that i came from a professional environment which do usually create components for everything that requires client-agnostic attachments using React/Inferno or similar frameworks).

From the perspective of HTML, data-src has no meaning to the DOM, it just provide an custom attribute that must be processed by javascript to get a meaning. Therefor a standardized BBCode for your approach is not known and any semantically valuable definition for alternative tags might reach a complexity where BBCodes are more complex than their resulting HTML.

One question that is still unanswered is: Do you aim for finding a BBCode who is able to express the specific HTML for the LazyLoad-PlugIn? If yes, there is none standardized, you have to create those in the concrete applications/implementations by yourself. If no, you should avoid standard BBCodes and provide an own BBCode who implements an tag of the exact required shape.